Find unused KMS keys
I tried to find out which KMS keys were not in use (I have 200+ KMS keys, and I believe that more than half of them are not used). For the discussion - not-in-use means were not used for more than 30 days)
Is there a good way I can do it programmatically \ using CLI?

See Determine past usage of a KMS key.

There is no direct way to get  it. You can try using CloudTrail Logs and create a simple script to audit key events. Example command:
aws cloudtrail lookup-events \
    --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=Encrypt \
    --start-time $(date -d '30 days ago' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') \
    --end-time $(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') \
    --output text

